# ASP.NET Core Web API cannot receive posted values: always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

My react front-end posted json data and asp.net core back-end always got value=null. How can it get values?

I tried `[FromForm]` `[FromBody]`, & `[FromQuery]`, but value is always null.

[Back-end core 2.2]

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("companies")]
        //public void Post([FromQuery] Data data)
        //public void Post(string data)
        //public void Post([FromBody] Data data)
        public void Post([FromForm] Data data)
        {
            // Cannot get data.values here.
        }
        public class Data
        {
            public string Value1 { get; set; } 
            public string Value2 { get; set; } 
        }
```

[Front-end]

```
    var Data = {
      Value1: "1",
      Value2: "2"
    };
    fetch('http://localhost:61980/api/values/companies', {
      method: 'POST',
      contentType : 'application/json',
      dataType: "json",
      // data: jsonData,
      data: JSON.stringify(Data),
      // body: JSON.stringify(Data),
      // body: "aaa",
      mode: 'no-cors'
    })
```

Back-end always got `data` with `data.Value1 = null` & `data.Value2 = null`.

Comment: You have `data: ` twice. `data: jsonData, data: JSON.stringify(Data)` remove one of two.

Comment: Thx, I just forgot to comment out it & it still doesn't work. I tried many ways and commented them out.

Comment: can you try making `public class Data
        {
            public string value1 { get; set; } 
            public string value2 { get; set; } 
        }`
small letter v.
and use FromBody

Comment: you need to use [FromBody] and also you need to set the body in the fetch..... headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(Data)

Comment: jQuery version I use: function PostModel(requestModel, url, successFunction, successParam) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(requestModel),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        headers: ComposeAntiForgeryTokenHeader(),
        success: function (resultModel) {
            
        }
    });
}

Comment: Thanks guys!! I spent almost all day then it works now! I got some other errors but the point is that I had to change value1&2 with small letter v, and add [FromBody] & headers. you guys saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

1) are your sure you are able hit to this end point? because as i can see your end point is companies, so i think it should be api/companies but you are trying to hit api/values/companies.

2) if first point is correct then try to hit this end point by using postman tool.

Comment: 1) my controller name is values, so it's correct. 2) yes I'm using postman. Thanks for your clarification :)